# what's the diff: FillRgn and PaintRgn in win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

FillRgn PaintRgn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FillRgn function takes a brush parameter while the PaintRgn uses the current brush in the device context.

Comment: Have another one.  These answers never get more than a thanks and one helpful vote.

Comment: +1 "never get more than a thanks and one helpful vote" – if you're lucky!